# Puts out validations to html in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to achieve how to put the validations error from backend to front end in rails

Here is my `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]+)\z/i
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_Sensitive:false }, format: { with: EMAIL_REGEX}
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

  before_save :email_lowercase

  # makes email lowercase before user submits

  def email_lowercase
    email.downcase!
  end

end
```

and here is my `user_controller.rb`:

```
  def create
    user = User.create(user_params)
    if user.valid?
      user.save
      redirect_to 'index'
    else
      user.errors.messages
      redirect_to '/users/new'
    end
  end
```

and this is my html form:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>

    <input type="text" name="user[name]" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input type="password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="password" name="user[confirm_pw]" placeholder="Confirm PW">
    <input type="submit" value="Join">

</form>
```

How can I puts out validations to html in rails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at section about adding validations in the [Getting Started with Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation) guide. There you'll find a good example. For your form, you could add the following:

```
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this user from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

For this to work, you'll also have to make some changes to your controller, so that you'll have a `@user` instance variable available.

Comment: This is the correct way to display errors on the form. But also, in your controller’s create action, if validation fails you should render the new action instead of redirecting to it. And, the `user` instance should be `@user`

Comment: How can I do specific error which is first name or email... not like any?